# MySQL optimizing orderby date query

Tags: mysql

I did my best to solve the following two simple queries but for each 10 rows result set it scans the full table or at least 10K rows. Currently there are 20000 rows in books table.

```
ALTER TABLE books ADD INDEX search_INX (`book_status`, `is_reviewed`,`has_image`,`published_date`)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT book_id FROM books ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | se ref  |lect_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | books | index | NULL          | search_INX | 11      | NULL | 20431 | Using index; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE book_status='available' AND is_reviewed=true AND has_image=true ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  ref               || possible_keys | key        | key_len | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | books | ref  | search_INX    | search_INX | 3       | const,const,const | 10215 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE book_status='available' AND is_reviewed=true AND has_image=true ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 10\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: books
         type: ref
possible_keys: search_INX
          key: search_INX
      key_len: 3
          ref: const,const,const
         rows: 10215
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `has_image` bit(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_reviewed` bit(1) NOT NULL default '\0',
  `book_status` enum('available','out of stock','printing') NOT NULL default 'available',
  `published_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`book_id`),
  KEY `search_INX` (`is_reviewed`,`has_image`,`book_status`,`published_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=162605 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does any one have clue to how to solve this problem?

Comment: @jason: i dun see a problem, the big rows is caused by the low cardinality, maybe u try running the query, and see how bad it is

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL (but am with others). The line "KEY `search_INX` (`is_reviewed`,`has_image`,`book_status`,`published_date`)" looks like a composite Key. Is it?

Comment: @IanC No its not composite key

Comment: So that's 4 separate indexes, one on each column?

Comment: @IanC I am not good at with DB terms. This is one index on four columns :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the problem is. I just looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html which confirms what I thought, and you just confirmed. If you take my suggestion in my second answer, you will solve your problem.

Comment: In reality, the query engine cannot possibly use the index as you have it because a composite index can only be queried from left to right, and you are querying the right.

Comment: @jason: to be clear, what is the exact question? Have you read my answer?

Comment: @zerkms: The question is Why MySQL scans high number rows? The link http://www.scribd.com/doc/2599381/MySQL-EXPLAIN-Cheatsheet tells that rows means: Approximation of # of rows returned. I have 20K total rows in the table and it scans more than 20K rows if I use IanC or thegreasyitalian solution

Comment: @jason: why do you think it **actually scans** that rows? Have you read my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169974/mysql-optimizing-orderby-date-query/4170023#4170023

Comment: @jason: don't believe things was written in that article. Read my answer and official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html "The rows column indicates the number of rows **MySQL believes it must examine** to execute the query. "

Comment: @jason:Try just running the queries if you want. If they're still too slow, then there's more room to talk, but IanC, zerkms, and I are all saying that just because it EXPLAINs it as 20K rows, doesn't mean it actually goes through each full row and scan it. Try the query and test the speed by your standards and benchmarks, and then get back to us.

Comment: @thegreasyitalian: actually, he did not even say us that those queries are slow :-S

Comment: @zerkms: True, true. Haha. Practically, like when I manage the db at my work with tens and hundreds of thousands of rows per table, I don't care about how many rows it's indexing if it gets done quickly! It's when it's slow that I make changes. Guess that's the engineer in me. Results matter.

Comment: @thegreasyitalian: it will matter when you'll get a database of >500gb ;-) /me sighs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, mysql in `rows` column show not the number of rows that was affected, but the **approximate** amount of rows that could be affected, **excluding** the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of:

```
KEY `search_INX` (`is_reviewed`,`has_image`,`book_status`,`published_date`)
```

...is poor. If you were to put published_date at the front, it would speed up your query. Further, why are you indexing is_reviewed & has_image? Boolean columns cannot even be indexed in the likes of SQL Server as there is no point to doing so (again, cardinality). Either rearrange your key, or put a unique key on the column I mentioned.

Comment: If I move the published_date to first position in the index it scans 20K rows if I keep the fields order same then it scans 10K rows. Clearly, field order is important.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Did you drop the original index? I still suggest, given your columns, you only index the 1 column.

Comment: what about the enum column? I think I am confused with EXPLAIN results. When I use the indexes that I have created it shows rows: 9644 when I remove my created index and add just date in the index then it shows me the rows: 20431.

Comment: "This is the correct solution" --- no, it is incorrect. If you move `published_date` to the first position in the index - then `WHERE` will not be covered with any leftmost part, so no index will be used.

Comment: @zerkms Well, that is debatable. The cardinality of only 3 possibilities is low enough to question if the query planner will even use the index. I don't know of any RDBMS that will use an index on a boolean field (column 2 in the index). In SQL Server, you can't even create one. However, the queries revolve heavily around something that has perfect cardinality: the date. Therefore the date is the most important piece of information.

Comment: @IanC: it is not related to type of indexes or cardinality. If there is no index, that covers `WHERE` - then mysql will no use any. And you propose to create index started with `publish_date`, so this index **doesn't cover** `WHERE` condition. So no index will be used, so you get a table fullscan.

Comment: @zerkms @Jason ok. Let's look at this logically. Jason has tried rearranging the indexes and that isn't solving it. @zerkms yes, what you said about the indexing is correct. Nevertheless, what I said is correct too. The bottom line is what I have been saying: query engines don't bother with low cardinality indexes (enum, bit, etc.). Therefore, nothing is going to change this. Putting the index on the date will help the query in SQL Server. It may not in MySQL.

Comment: Perforce, the way I see it is the only way to speed this up is to include the date in the where, thereby forcing a limit on the amount of data being queried. This could be tricky, but possible. It would require some smart coding.

Comment: @IanC: "query engines don't bother with low cardinality indexes" --- the cardinality is calculated for the whole index, not for its parts. Since his index contains the data as the last part - it has a **good cardinality**.

Comment: @zerkms Sure, but ideally the cardinality should be at the **beginning part**, not the last part.

Comment: @IanC: indeed, that cardinality is meaningful only for **used part** of index. And since @jason has only low-cardinality types in 3 leftmost parts and in `where` it could be bad. **BUT**, the `ORDER` part also takes part in the query evaluation  (and it adds a better cardinality) and I bet that it helps much. Anyway, he did not say that his queries are slow. Peace ;-)

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, the problem seems to be you're missing an index on published_date. Order by is using this column. Add this index and see what happens.

Comment: its in question: ALTER TABLE books ADD INDEX search_INX (`book_status`, `is_reviewed`,`has_image`,`published_date`)

Comment: @jason: and `published_date` is not the leftmost part

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on indexing, but can you create an index just on published_date as well as the index you have made on all four fields?

```
ALTER TABLE books DROP INDEX `search_INX`;
ALTER TABLE books ADD INDEX `published_INX` (`published_date`);
```

Comment: As in, your keys currently are a Primary Key on `book_id` and a multiple-column key on 4 different columns, so you may want to have a key just on `published_date` so the ORDER BY statement works more efficiently.

Comment: I did but its not making any difference. After using Force Index it scans the full table

Comment: I'm not suggesting you force index. I am saying to drop the `search_INX` key and add a new key on just `published_date`. Or follow @IanC answer on the cardinality of that `search_INX`. Either way, that `search_INX` needs to be dropped and better index(es) should be added.

Comment: @Jason, @thegreasyitalian and I are giving the correct and probably only answer.

Comment: I added drop and add lines for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the FORCE INDEX command, does that help?

Comment: the index is already show in Explain so there is no need to use FORCE INDEX

Answer (score 0):

@Zerkms @jason I just thought of another way to solve this.

It is unorthodox, but would work. If your primary key was (publish_date, book_id) with DESC sort, you would easily be able to get the last 10 results. The query engine would scan the table, applying the where clause, until it found 10 results, then quit.

It would work great. Just add another index on book_id if you need to specifically query by book_id.

The reason this makes sense is the DB would naturally store books by date (InnoDB uses clustered indexes), which is exactly what you are trying to query.

Comment: I read elsewhere that DESC isn't possible in MySQL. Still, this would work. Alternately, invert the date first. Wikipedia is an example of using inversion to create a negative "DESC" sequence.